# Duplicate Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script triggers and permissions

Tags: spreadsheet

I have a google spreadsheet with an associated script and two manually triggers, furthermore protected cells, etc. It is the model of the teacher's gradebook that we want to have in my school. The problem comes when I want to create 50 copies, one for each teacher, where all of them have to have the script, the triggers, protected cells, etc. I've gotten everything except the manual triggers. What I can do? What solution can there be? Create it as a plugin? You can make a Chrome add-on that creates that Spreadsheet for you with everything you need (triggers, script, protected cells, formulas ...)
Help!

Thanks.